# Adding Event Listeners on multiprocessing.Manager

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have two machines, and right now the child is doing a while 1: statement to constantly check the BaseManager that holds the jobs.  This makes it chatty.  Is there a better way to do this?

Can you create an event on the manager that says "Hey I have a new job children!" like in C# where you could wire up a new event using the += and -= syntax?

Very simply the child is like this:

```
class QueueManager(BaseManager):
""" multiprocessing queue manager object """
     pass
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # get the get function
    QueueManager.register('get_queue')
    while 1:
       queue = m.get_queue()
       if queue.empty() == False and \
           queue.qsize() > 0:
           job_directory = queue.get()
           print job_directory
```

all I'm doing it pulling the job folder from the queue.  I would like a better way to do this.  Can events be wired up to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for a busy loop here. Just call `get_queue` once, outside of the while loop, and then use `queue.get()` directly inside the loop:

```
class QueueManager(BaseManager):
""" multiprocessing queue manager object """
     pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    QueueManager.register('get_queue')
    queue = m.get_queue()
    while 1:
       job_directory = queue.get()
       print job_directory
```

The manager is returning a `Proxy` to the `Queue.Queue()` object you created on the server, not a copy of the actual `Queue.Queue` object. Every operation you do on the `Proxy` gets passed through to the instance of the `Queue.Queue` on the server, so you can just use it like you would a normal `Queue`. From the client's perspective, a shared `Queue` instance returned by a `BaseManager` subclass is no different from a plain-old `Queue.Queue`.

Comment: so the recommended pattern is to always use the while 1 pattern?

Comment: @josh1234 Yes. Because we're now going straight to `queue.get()`, using a `while 1:` pattern isn't very "chatty". The loop will block in the `get()` call until there's actually an item in the `queue` to consume. Then it will just process it, and go right back to blocking.